# Vim Send Alt-F10 Keys at Startup

Tags: linux, vim

I need to send Alt-F10 key combination at vim startup. I am on Linux Mint. I tried: `au GUIEnter * call feedkeys("\<M-F10>")`.
But that didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? [(XY Problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/188334)

Comment: In my Linux Mint, if I press Alt-F10, it will maximize the current application.

Comment: You are right. It's XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [:simalt](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui_w32.txt.html#%3Asimalt) command.

[VimFAQ 33.3. - 'How do I start GUI Vim in a maximized window always?'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-33.3) shows a example similar to what you have attempted:

```
autocmd GUIEnter * simalt ~x
```

---

**Edit:**

The `simalt` command is only available for ms-windows, so it will only display an error message on Linux.

You can make gVim become similar to a maximized window by using large values for `'lines'` and `'columns'` options, by adding the following to your vimrc:

```
set columns=1000
set lines=100
```

You could change to maximized state by using feedkeys, as you mentioned you have tried. On Linux Mint with LXDE the command `call feedkeys("\<M-F10>")` displays gVim 'File' menu: 'Open, Save, Print, Exit, etc'. Here the command to open the menu and hit 'Maximize' is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>,<kbd>x</kbd>. But unfortunately it is not easy to send `<A-space>` from gVim, similar to what [is discussed on this post](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/imap-Alt-Space-please-help-lt-td5721993.html). If your windows manager also relays on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> you should try to change its configuration (for LXDE it is on ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml) to use some other key combination and then send it through `feedkeys()`.

A third option is the [shell plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-shell), which provides a `:Maximize` command.

Comment: I think simalt for Windows. In the documentation it says - "{not in Vi} {only for Win32 versions}". I am on Linux Mint. However, simalt ~x is for Win-key + Up (I think). What is for Alt-F10?

Comment: @Joydeep I have included more info on the answer.

Comment: I have already tried 
`set columns=999`
`set lines=999`
But, it does not maximize the whole window.
But once again, forget maximize. My question is, how do I send Alt-F10 key combination at vim startup on Linux Mint?

Comment: @Joydeep "My question is, how do I send Alt-F10 key combination..." -- As I have already stated on the answer,I have tested `call feedkeys("\<M-F10>")` on Linux Mint with LXDE and it worked fine. It also work as expected with the autocmd GUIEnter. Without further information from your side is really hard to provide any help.